# Convert mp3 to ogg?

Tags: mp3, convert

I want to convert my entire music library to ogg format from mp3. while keeping the folder/file format I have under music and keep the tags that are on them.

Comment: If you don't mind using the command line, see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/147944/bulk-batch-convert-mp3-files-to-ogg-via-command-line

Comment: Close-voters: This is *not* a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147944/bulk-batch-convert-mp3-files-to-ogg-via-command-line); that question is considerably narrower. It could potentially be edited to make it broader, but it's not a good idea to dupe this to it until then (and we should probably hold off on doing that, too, to see what kind of answers appear here and if it makes sense to try to make these one question).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a good soundconverter called "soundconverter" in the Softwarecenter. I made the test, tags are maintained when converting from .mp3 to .ogg.

You can install it with the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo apt install soundconverter
```

Comment: omg, it makes multithread conversion of all files same time automatically (no need to select the format) :O

Answer (score 0):

For command line usage there is a nice package [dir2ogg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dir2ogg.1.html).